# Handling jQuery AJAX Errors globally

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, error-handling

What are your guys thoughts on globally handling AJAX errors, displaying any/all info in the console?

As of right now I do something like this:

```
jSpace._displayAjaxErrors = function (xhrResponseText) {

    var errObj = $.parseJSON(xhrResponseText);

    // _log is an internal console log that won't break in IE (aka does nothing)
    _self._log('\n -- AJAX ERROR @ ' + _self._getTimeStamp() + ' --');

    _self._log('ExceptionType : '   + errObj.ExceptionType);
    _self._log('Error Message : '   + errObj.Message);
    _self._log('StackTrace    : \n' + errObj.StackTrace);​

    // then a dialogBox here
};
```

And each `.ajax()` has this included at the moment:

```
error: function (xhr, status, error) {
    jSpace._displayAjaxErrors(xhr.responseText);
}
```

I'm not familiar with [.ajaxError()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/), **but wondering if there is a better way of doing all of this!**

**What do you do to easily see what/where the errors are?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery already provide `ajaxError` function to catch all ajax error globally, you just need to use that

```
$( "div.log" ).ajaxError(function(e, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
  //e for event 
  //jqxhr for xhrResponse
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

Comment: I've been reading about it, but what is this div.log? I'm assuming I can just create the div there on the fly `$('<div class="log" />').ajaxError(function () {});` right? I just want everything to be logged mainly

Comment: You may create `<div class="log" />` or just use `$.ajaxError` is OK no problem

Comment: That's awesome! I'll play around with this and add my events in there then. Any idea if having `error: function () { }` on a page automatically overwrites `.ajaxError()`?

Comment: You can have additional error: somewhere else :), It  will not overwrite but call both of them